# Clarification on Heads First Javascript Book puzzle

Tags: javascript

Why did sherlock decide not to investigate the case? How could he know that the criminal would never be able to steal the money just by looking at the code? Is there one problem with the code? Or more? Here's our solution.

```
  var balance = 10500;
var cameraOn = true;

function steal(balance, amount) {
    cameraOn = false;
    if (amount < balance) {
        balance = balance - amount;
    }
    return amount;
    cameraOn = true;





}


var amount = steal(balance, 1250);
console.log("Criminal: you stole " + amount + "!");
```

Now the book points out that the balance put parameter is shadowed. And that the security camera isn't turned back on. I have been trying to fix this so it would work. I moved the return amount; after the cameraOn = true; 
Would the cameraOn need to be returned? as it is also a global within the function?
And what would the best approach for updating the balance be? I tried updating it after the function but I was thinking the function should really update it? And then return balance; ?

Any direction would be appreciated as the book doesn't tell you the approach to fix it. I'm just trying to get my head around it.

Comment: cameraOn = true; after return does nothing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Stmt_after_return

Comment: So if cameraOn is placed before the return, does this update the global cameraOn? Or do i need to return this value also?

Comment: If you ain't able to come up with an answer, it isn't a good book.

Answer (score 0):

> Would the cameraOn need to be returned?

If *steal* should return the booleans value yes. If not, no theres no need to.

> as it is also a global within the function?

Rather as its part of the *global scope* and the function is inside that global scope.

> And what would the best approach for updating the balance be?

```
 amount = steal(Infinity, Infinity);
```

Now you are richer than a billionaire ;)

How my bank looks like:

> A block to encapsulate the balance:
>
> ```
> {
>  let balance = 1250;
>
>  function steal(amount){
>    if(amount >= balance){
>      balance -= amount;
>      return true;
>    }
>    return false
>  }
>
> }
> ```